# Is there a better way to write this if-statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

What is the better way of doing this:

```
if pattern[0] != [0] or pattern[0] != [0 , 0] or ... so on:
    # do something
```

Comment: Is there a limit, or do you want to detect up to an infinity of zeros? In any case, since `pattern[0]` can't be both `[0]` and `[0,0]` at the same time, you can change the whole thing to `if True:` :-) Or did you mean `and` rather than `or`?

Comment: well let's say the limit is 20 of zeros [ 0, 0, ->18 more ]

Comment: what is the `else` case?

Comment: @paxdiablo if `pattern` is `[[0, 0]]` could it not fit `pattern[0] != [0 , 0]`?

Comment: @Brandon, if it _is_ `[[0,0]]`, then `pattern[0] != [0]` is true. In fact, the whole `if` statement condition is true regardless of what `pattern` is set to. That's my point.

Comment: @paxdiablo I missed it at first but I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for  [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(pattern[0]):
```

This solution tests if any of the items in `pattern[0]` are not equal to `0`.  It works because `0` evaluates to `False` in Python.  Of course, it also assumes that `pattern[0]` is iterable since you were comparing it to lists originally.

Also, the condition of your if-statement is incorrect regardless of what you are trying to do.  It will always be `True` because `pattern[0]` will always be either not equal to `[0]` or not equal to `[0, 0]`.  You should be using `and` instead of `or`:

```
if pattern[0] != [0] and pattern[0] != [0 , 0] and ... so on:
```

Comment: Until OP clarifies the question re use of `and` or `or`, this is technically wrong. It's _probably_ right but you may want to note the discepency in your answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo well I need it for OR(as i asked above), but will be nice to have with AND for future reference.